# Releasing and publishing from sbt-bintray

Tags: sbt, bintray, sbt-release

I'm trying to publish to bintray a relase for my library. I already released several versions [till now](https://bintray.com/raisercostin/maven/jedi-io/view).

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: error uploading to https://api.bintray.com/maven/raisercostin/maven/maven/org/raisercostin/jedi-io_2.10/0.22/jedi-io_2.10-0.22.pom: 
    {"message":"Unable to upload files: Maven group, artifact or version defined in the pom file do not match the file path 'org/raisercostin/jedi-io_2.10/0.22/jedi-io_2.10-0.22.pom'"}
        at bintray.BintrayMavenRepository.put(Resolver.scala:27)
        at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.put(RepositoryResolver.java:234)
```

I'm using [bintray-sbt](https://github.com/softprops/bintray-sbt) via `project/plugins.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("me.lessis" % "bintray-sbt" % "0.3.0")
```

The project with full details is hosted on [github/jedi-io](https://github.com/raisercostin/jedi-io).

I noticed a double `maven/maven` in the api url and tried to "fix" it using a custom bintray-sbt and it didn't work with either: `https://api.bintray.com/maven/raisercostin/maven/org/raisercostin/jedi-io_2.10/0.22/jedi-io_2.10-0.22.pom`

Comment: I suspect this could be a bug at bintray, I just hit the same problem.  It works if I publish ivy style, but then the dependency isn't resolved when i try to pull it in to another project. Mine was also working until just now.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I added a workaround. The bug is present in the UI as well so you cannot manually upload the files using maven format.

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround I enabled publishing ivy style with `publishMavenStyle := false` and defined an additional ivy resolver in the using app `resolvers += Resolver.url("raisercostin ivy resolver", url("http://dl.bintray.com/raisercostin/maven"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)`

Comment: Ahh... i was missing the Resolver.ivyStylePatterns... now it works for me too, I had noticed earlier that using publishMavenStyle := false let it publish... in the mean time i'd just been doing publishLocal :P